# regex and grep match only string with only single or double digit

Tags: regex, grep

I need to extract a string with only single or double digit number in them. my file (test) looks like

```
test1correct
test12something
test123wrong
```

In the above example, i want to grep only for 
test1correct  and test12something

I tried this
grep "test[0-9]{1,2}" test but it gives me all the 3 lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use: `grep "test[0-9]{1,2}[^0-9]`"

Comment: Can anyone explain this regex?

Comment: Explanation: `grep "^test[0-9]\{1,2\}[^0-9]" test.txt` which will work everywhere. Basically you are trying to fetch only those lines where the `starting word` of the line is `test` i.e. `^test` (see `^` character which means starting point/character of a line as given), then search for number `[0-9]\{1,2\}` (between 0 to 9, backslash before `{` and `}` is required) and then to avoid a 3 digit number, the next character after 1 or 2 digit number can be anything other than a number therefore, `[^0-9]` which means, NOT a number (when `^` is used within big brackets `[` and `]`).

Answer (score 2):

Using lookaheads and lookbehinds you can specify "exactly one digit" or "exactly three digits" or whatever.  This does exactly one digit:

```
echo 'WB123_4' | grep -Po '(?<![[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]{1})(?![[:digit:]])'
Result: 4
```

What it is doing is, find a digit that is not preceded by a digit, and also not followed by a digit.  Also works for more than one digit.  This does three digits, then at least one of anything else, then one digit:

```
echo 'WB123_4' | grep -Po '(?<![[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]{3})(?![[:digit:]]).+(?<![[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]{1})(?![[:digit:]])'
Result: 123_4
```

While I'm at it, this combination of grep and sed will find a string with three digits, then one or more of anything else, then one digit, and extract just those parts nicely.  (There might have been another way to do that just in grep with groups.)

```
echo 'WB123_4' | grep -Po '(?<![[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]{3})(?![[:digit:]]).+(?<![[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]{1})(?![[:digit:]])' | sed -r -e 's/[^[:digit:]]+/ /'
Result: 123 4
```

Note: the -P flag to grep means to use Perl-style regular expressions, which lets you use lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
test[0-9]{1,2}[A-Za-z]+
```